# Changed all files on computer to 0777 by accident

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, permissions

I only wanted to change the permissions of a folder which contains a lot of other folders and files, but ended up changing everything from root ( / ).

I searched for "change permissions of all files and subdirectories linux" and ended up finding this: [How to set chmod for a folder and all of its subfolders and files in Linux Ubuntu Terminal? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt). I used the code which had the top upvotes, except that I removed the path because I thought I didn't need it because I was already in the folder I wanted to change. What I didn't think through, was the little forward slash I put in there, so everything changed to 777

```
find / -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Now I can't access it with ssh or sftp. What should I do to change the permissions back again?

Comment: This is a restore from backup/reinstall scenario.

Comment: Is there a standard warning we should put above that command so others don't copy and paste it by mistake?

Comment: there are already many duplicate and related questions [Is it safe to chmod 777 everything?](https://superuser.com/q/1034079/241386), [Accidentally did `chmod -777 /`](https://askubuntu.com/q/471590/253474), [Chmod 777 to a folder and all contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8328481/995714), [Why is `chmod -R 777 /` destructive?](https://serverfault.com/q/364677/343888), [Wrongly set `chmod / 777`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12998/44425), [How to fix permissions after `chmod -r 777 /`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37157020/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, there is no old value of file permissions stored anywhere in the system, hence Joe's answer-as-a-comment that one must

- restore from backup, or
- reinstall.

Comment: Yes, I learn from my mistakes, and that's a good thing.